# What does this mean: "document.write('<scr'+'ipt... "?

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen this on every Yahoo! [news page](http://news.yahoo.com/s/ap/20090924/ap_on_he_me/med_aids_vaccine), at the bottom of the source code,
and failed to understand why they break the **script** word like that.

Does anybody know if there's any reason for this?

```
document.write("<scr"+"ipt language=javascript src=http://l.yimg.com/d/lib/bc/bc_2.0.4.js></scr"+"ipt>");
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Consider this simplified example:

```
<script>
document.write("something </script> something");
</script>
```

The browser's HTML parser would see the `</script>` within the JavaScript string and interpret that as the end of the script element.

The HTML parser doesn't know about JavaScript syntax - all it knows is that the `<script>` element ends at the next `</script>`.

(It also knows that you can't have nested `<script>` elements, hence the breaking of the opening `<script>` as well as the closing `</script>` in your example.)

Comment: Note: The same way behaves the colouring of the code in SO. Notice the "something" being treated as a text content outside of the script element.

Comment: Actually, no, SCRIPT element ends at first occurrence of "</", not only "</script>". See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata

Comment: Is this a workaround for old browsers or does it apply even to modern browsers?

Comment: @hasen j: It applies to modern browsers - my example goes wrong in Firefox 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you are writing a tool that detects the beginning and end of script blocks in a chunk of text. Suppose you see

```
<blah><blahdeblah><script>

blah blah blah

blah

print("</script>")

print("<script>")

blah

</script>

</blahdeblah></blah>
```

Without knowing the syntax of the script language, how does your tool know that this is ONE script block and not TWO script blocks with ")blah between them?

A web browser is such a tool. It's a reasonable practice to make sure you never confuse the web browser by never having `<script>` or `</script>` in your file unless it actually is a script tag.

Answer (score 3):

so that it doesn't get evaluated but gets inserted as a string.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad way to prevent XML/XHTML and HTML validators from yelling at the source code.

Comment: So why does Google Analytics uses this method if it's bad? "document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js"... why do they even do it with document.write I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers tend to "act" to fast when parsing a document and immediately try to execute the javascript when they find a script tag (even though it is itself in a piece of js). To avoid this they break the decalration of the tag.

Comment: I didn't quite understood what you have just said, can you supply further reading on the subject please? it very very interesting.

Comment: Say you open a page with IE, that has document.write('<script type..etc">'); on it somewhere on the page. IE might incorrectly parse that document.write('<script type..etc">'); and think, "hey, a script tag!" and then executes that code (because it thinks it's just an inline script block). But in reality that document.write('<script type..etc">'); is not supposed to be executed until say the entire page has loaded or until some other condition is met (which can be anything ranging from a user inputting some text etc. etc.) By breaking the <script tag the browser won;t ever misparse it.

Answer (score 0):

For a full discussion of this, see:
   http://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2007/04/25/using-script-in-a-javascript-literal/

The short answer is that your code is parsed in two discrete steps.

The first one is XML. And that means that the element <SCRIPT> is looking for a </SCRIPT>. It's important to remember that XML elements are content agnostic. That means that the parser doesn't know *yet* that there's JavaScript in there.

Once it has the contents of the <SCRIPT> element, *then* it processes that chunk of text, which presumably is JavaScript.

By splitting up the tag with a string concatenate operator you prevent a constant from tripping up the XML phase.

One simple solution is to put &lt; and &gt; in the Javascript text.

Comment: All good, except that it's parsed as HTML (that is, SGML), not XML. HTML has very specific wording for `<script>`, which basically says that it has to parse the content ignoring any mentions of unescaped `<`, `>` and `&`, until it sees `</script>`. Hence why this JS trick works. XML, on the other hand, would just barf on the first `<` inside, unless you use CDATA (and if you do use CDATA, then you do not need JS trick).