# jslint flagging "dangerous comment"

Tags: javascript, jslint

Given this JavaScript code (which is just a comment referring to a url):

```
// see http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/
```

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) with "Safe Subset" turned on will say

```
Dangerous comment.
// http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/
```

How can a *comment* be dangerous?  Comments, by definition, aren't parsed!  Or are they?

**Edit:** Using a different url isn't necessarily dangerous.  For example this:

```
// http://enterprisejquery.com
```

doesn't trigger the flag.  How can one URL in a comment be 'dangerous', but another isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Dangerous" comments match the regular expression:

```
/@cc|<\/?|script|\]\s*\]|<\s*!|&lt/i
```

In this case, your comment is "dangerous" because it contains the string "script".

I think this is probably a false positive.

Comment: You're right-- this is [script block paranoia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474185/what-does-this-mean-document-writescript).  Wow, I wish jslint would just say that.

Comment: btw, just doing `// script` triggers it. Or in the question example, replacing 'javascript' with 'foo' makes the error go away.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute comments manually using `eval`:

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/09/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-reducing.html

> To combine all modules into a single resource, we wrote each module
>   into a separate script tag and hid the code inside a comment block (/*
>   */). When the resource first loads, none of the code is parsed since it is commented out. To load a module, find the DOM element for the
>   corresponding script tag, strip out the comment block, and eval() the
>   code.

Also, someone might accidently uncomment the dangerous code and create a vulnerability.

By default, no, JavaScript comments are not parsed. But there are not a nice thing to have lying around.

Comment: JSLint doesn't think that all URLs-in-comments are dangerous, tho.  I've edited my question to show this.  Why are some URLs dangerous but others aren't?

Comment: Also, since the comment _isn't actually javascript_, how can it be dangerous?  Wouldn't the eval just fail?

Comment: Good question. I guess Samuel answered that question. But his answer just raises another question of why that regex is actually considered dangerous.

Comment: It's worried about triggering an [end-script block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474185/what-does-this-mean-document-writescript).  But I think the regex is capturing too much, as it even matches against 'script', which is obviously not dangerous.