# How to defeat browser caching in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

After reading several threads, there are two basic solutions I have come across.

One involves asking browser not to cache - >
Using HTML meta tags S1:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" /> 
<meta http-equiv='expires' content="-1"/>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content="no-cache"/>
```

It didn't work for me.

Other was to put random number after the URL

S2:

```
<script language="javascript" src="./js/myJS.js?'+ Math.Random()*100+'"/>
```

These work on Chrome and Mozilla but for some reason they aren't working for me on IE.

**Does someone know an alternative way?**

I can't get to embed S2 into script block. If it can be done then this might work.

```
<script> 
document.write("<script language=\"javascript\" src=\"./js/myJS.js?'+ Math.Random()*100+'\"/>") 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried escaping the script tags?

```
<script >
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='./js/myJS.js?r=" + Math.random().toString().replace('.', '') + "' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Rudy, it worked! I guess, the encoding fools the HTML parser into believing that the characters are usual string.

Comment: This approach is not working with CSS style-sheets.

<link REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="./{a/css/@bscss}/css/default.css"/>


was changed to

<script >
    document.write(unescape("%3Clink REL='STYLESHEET' TYPE='text/css' HREF='./{a/css/@bscss}/css/default.css?" +  new Date().getTime() + "' /%3E"));
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Your solution 2 is the right way to do it, but you can't write the string "<script/>" inside a <script> tag as it confuses the HTML parser. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474185/what-does-this-mean-document-writescript) for more info.

You can circumvent this problem with the following trick :

```
<script> 
<![CDATA[document.write("<script language=\"javascript\" src=\"./jsdir/RS_01_eng.js?'+ Math.Random()*100+'\"><\/script>")]]>
</script>
```

I also suggest that you drop the language="javascript" as it is no longer necessary in HTML5.

Also maybe you should switch from *Math.Random() * 100* to *new Date().getTime()* in order to have something more unique and prevent the 1 in a hundred time edge case.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but didn't work. Maybe because i need to embed this in  XSL ...... It says ERROR:  'Element type "scr" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".'

Comment: Didn't work as in the cache is still there or the script wasn't loaded?

Comment: Script didnt run. 

The XSL gave the compilation error and above is the reason for it. It needs closing of scr. You did fool JS with that :) but XSL isnt.

Comment: Ha ! I didn't notice XSL was involved. I added CDATA tags to counteract the XSL processor. That should do the trick.

Comment: That does the trick for XSL ! but sadly my problem isn't solved. It still shows the cached copy. But I think you should edit your answer and show both the solutions, it could help someone using JS.

Comment: Try to do a hard-refresh (CTRL+F5) just once and test again. Maybe the old code is still in there. Also, what webserver are you using ? How does your file change exactly ?

Comment: I can do hard-refresh but cannot enforce this on the customers. Weblogic. Rudy's method worked for me. 
I thought it was due to replacing decimal. So I tested your solution with Math.Random().toString().replace('.', ''). Still it shows old cached copy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Answer taken from: [Using <meta> tags to turn off caching in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Edit: I know you've tried some meta-tags, but similar tags as written above have worked for me in the past.